# "the Pashto language"

Tags: articles, definite-article

I started the abstract of a paper that I am writing with this sentence:

> Pashto language belongs to the eastern Iranian branch of the Indo-European family of languages, and it is spoken primarily in Afghanistan and Pakistan by over 50 million people.

Grammarly says that I have to add the "the" article at the beginning of the sentence "the Pashto language....".

Should I add the "the" or not? which makes more sense?

Comment: Just use 'Pashto' every time. Especially in a linguistics paper, it is unnecessary to point out that it is a language constantly, because many linguists have heard of Pashto. And also, it's just bad style to repeat the three-word phrase over and over, when a single word will do.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is an NLP paper. My audience does know that Pashto is a language.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need the "The."  "Pashto" functions as an adjective, and therefore the grammatical structure would be the same if you removed it.  Then you would get

> Language belongs to the eastern Iranian branch

That does not work.  Therefore you must say, "The language," and insert the adjective to get "The Pashto" language.

Comment: okay. Thank you so much. Two more questions: if I remove the 'language' too, just start with 'Pashto belongs to eastern....' would that be correct? and the second question: I use 'Pashto language' a lot inside my paper. Should add 'the' every time?

Comment: I really appreciate your answerers Mary! thank you mcuh